# matplotlib - set correct colorbar as for plot and colorbar number labels to correspond to real data range

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

In the example code below, I am colorizing the data points of a sinus plot according to the values of the third data column (z).

Now I would like to plot a colorbar with the corresponding chosen color map (here 'hsv'), and the numbers beside the colorbar should be in the range between min(z) and max(z) (from 0 to 999).

I am first scaling the data to the range between 0 and 1, so I understand why the numbering of the color bar is between 0 and 1. Nevertheless, I would like to change the numbers to be between min(z) and max(z).

And what I do not understand is the color table of the colorbar, which is different from 'hsv'.

What do I wrong?

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib as mpl

cmap = mpl.colormaps['hsv']

n = 1000

x = np.arange(n)/n*2*np.pi
y = np.sin(x)
z = np.arange(n)

colvals = preprocessing.minmax_scale(z)

plt.scatter(x, y,  color=cmap(colvals), marker='.', s=100)
plt.colorbar(orientation='vertical', label='z')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it, and it is the same plot. Do you see also the different color maps for plot and colorbar?

Comment: @JohanC: Please see https://imgur.com/gallery/JOvU5Iy

Comment: The normal way to call scatter would be `plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='hsv', marker='.', s=100)`.  That should automatically make sure the colorbar gets the correct colors and ranges. (Note the use of `c=` instead of `color=`).

Comment: If you like, post this as an answer, so I can mark it as solved.